# fitting a curve to water data using python

Tags: regression, time-series, python, nonparametric, curve-fitting

I an engineer trying to fit a curve to water data. I have daily data for water usage (volume and timestamp). Timestamp is in minutes. I have say 20 weeks of data.

What Ive done to the data:
Got a daily average for each of the 20 weeks.  And was able to plot these on one plot, with each line representing a weeks daily average.

What Id like:

- Get a mode that tells me what we expect the usage to be like..using the data I already have. The model should use all the given weeks data to create the model
- I want to use this to predict future usage
- I would also like the model to improve if and when given an extra weeks data.
- I dont already know the shape of the model

I am very inexperienced with statistics and applied maths.  So far I've read up on non-parametric regression, Kernel regression. The maths is still very foreign to me.

Helping me decide on 2 to 3 methods that can achieve this.

Inserting 4 weeks data.

[image: Data-each line represents each week's average daily usage]

[image: Snippet of the data]

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data? Since you have (24 hrs * 7 days * 20 weeks) over 3,300 data points it would be impractical to directly post the raw data. From your description, the data does not seem to have seasonal summer vs.winter information, but you have to work with what you have, and keep this in mind when applying model predictions of future usage.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forecasting?sort=votes&pageSize=50

Comment: The raw data?  There is an extra variable, temp (for seasonality).  For now I'd like to start with a basic model and hopefully build on that.

Comment: I do have a csv with the data used to create this above graph, how do i share that here?

Comment: Firstly have you tried any time-series model for it. As we can see that you have time-stamp with data so it is time series data. Please try some uni-variate time series models like AR(Auto-regressive) and MA( Moving average). AS you have mentioned in point 3 you will get extra data, then surely it have seasonality as well as trend.

Comment: Thank you, I basically need to be pointed in the right direction.  After some reason it became apparent that theres alot of different methods I could use and I don't have the knowledge to chose the most appropriate one.

Comment: Post a link to the data file. By the way, the possibility of regressing Usage = f(time, temp) exists - I'll try my hand at both types of regression if you post a a link to the csv file.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N0iqQkkGmtAvQSHAZCoVwVM4rBmWq-vriGXBSG3GfkI/edit#gid=1905318722

Comment: The linked file is not public, so I cannot open it.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/home/Public?preview=All_Week_data.csv   it should work now

Comment: Dropbox is requiring a login to access the file.

Comment: I did make it public, not sure what I missed. Whats the easiest way to make it accessible to you?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r2xwut1inuzg2aa/All_Week_data.csv?dl=0

Comment: I can access the file, but it does not have 3,300 data points.

Comment: I only added some of the processed data. This has been processed and cleaned. I will add the raw data shortly.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lmpjvfzug9wadbd/Data.csv?dl=0

Comment: OK, I have the large raw data file. For the data in this file, the header is "Cm,Hm,_id,changed,imei,time" - should I directly regress Cm = f(Hm, time)?

Comment: The variables of interest are Cm (volume) and time (timestamp).  You can regress predicted_vol = f(Cm, time).  Hm and the others are not of interest for now

Comment: Most excellent. I am beginning my analysis now. Check back over the next day or two for my results.

Comment: And the temp data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70361/discussion-between-che-and-james-phillips).

Comment: I want to now use KNN regression for prediction. what form should the x and y data have? I have read the documentation and I am still lost.